# script commands for winbugs

Tags: winbugs, winbugs14

If I'm running my model in Winbugs14 via a script, what's the command for thinning, or drawing box-plots? I know some of the basic commands, for example:

```
set(x)
update(1000)
density(alpha)
```

but I couldn't find the commands for thinning, or drawing model-fit, or drawing box-plots on Winbugs14 documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete list of commands is on pages 34-35 of the user manual:

https://faculty.washington.edu/jmiyamot/p548/spiegelhalter%20winbugs%20user%20manual.pdf

In particular I think you want:

```
thin.updater(thin)
dic.set()
dic.stats()
```

I'm not sure there is a command to draw boxplots but that can be done in other software e.g. R.

I guess you already know this, but development of WinBUGS stopped years ago, so you really should switch to either OpenBUGS or JAGS at some point soon.  I am admittedly biased, but I think that the runjags R package is a good route for people that are familiar with WinBUGS but not as much with R - you could take a look at the first section of:

http://runjags.sourceforge.net/quickjags.html